# Is there a way define a second property type based on a key used in a separate property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a filter type which takes the primary object type to define a set of keys for "field" and will map the specified field to properly type "value"; however, the closest I could get is a union of the possible value types. Most documentation I could find was related to functions with works perfectly - just not sure how to get a type to span multiple properties for this situation. If this is possible, I'm also curious if there is a way to define the "operator" union to only include items such as "startswith" if the value type is a string. Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated. Example code:

```
type FilterItem<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    field: K;
    value: T[K];
    operator: 'eq'|'neq'|'startswith'|'doesnotstartwith';
}
type Test = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
const filter = {
    field: 'age',
    value: 'test', //should error as "age" is a number
    operator: 'startswith' //should error as "age" is not a string
} as FilterItem;
```

Comment: ?? `startswith` and `startsWith` are different.  Could you make sure there are no typos (especially because strings have a `startsWith` method, so it's potentially distracting)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDD6VN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you want your `filter` variable to be of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with one member for every property of `Test`.  Like this:

```
type FilterItemTest = {
    field: "name";
    value: string;
    operator: "startswith" | "doesnotstartwith" | "eq" | "neq";
} | {
    field: "age";
    value: number;
    operator: "eq" | "neq";
}
```

Once you do that then you get the desired behavior (or at least you get errors on invalid assignments, if not on any particular invalid properties; see [microsoft/TypeScript#39438](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39438) and [microsoft/TypeScript#40934](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40934) for more information):

```
let filter: FilterItemTest;
filter = { field: 'age', value: 10, operator: "eq" } // okay
filter = { field: 'age', value: 'test', operator: 'startswith' } // error, value incompatible
filter = { field: 'age', value: 10, operator: 'startswith' } // error, operator incompatible
filter = { field: 'name', value: 'test', operator: 'startswith' } // okay
```

---

So that means you want `FilterItem<T>` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the object type `T` corresponding to `Test`, and produce the desired union from it.  Here's one way to accomplish that.

First let's define `Operator<T>` to represent the acceptable values for the `operator` property given a property of type `T`:

```
type Operator<T> =
    (T extends string ? 'startswith' | 'doesnotstartwith' : never)
    | 'eq' | 'neq'
```

That's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which only includes `'startswith'` and `'doesnotstartwith'` if `T` has any `string` values in its domain.  Let's make sure it behaves as desired:

```
type OperatorString = Operator<string>;
// type OperatorString = "startswith" | "doesnotstartwith" | "eq" | "neq"
type OperatorNumber = Operator<number>;
// type OperatorNumber = "eq" | "neq"
```

Okay, now we can define `FilterItem<T>`:

```
type FilterItem<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {
    field: K;
    value: T[K];
    operator: Operator<T[K]>
} }[keyof T]
```

This is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties of `T` to get an object whose property values are the desired union members, and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with the union of keys to get the desired output.  Essentially we're distributing the `{field: K, value: T[K], operator: Operator<T[K]>}` operation across the union of `K` values in `keyof T`.

Let's make sure it works as desired:

```
type Test = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

type FilterItemTest = FilterItem<Test>;
/* type FilterItemTest = {
  field: "name";
  value: string;
  operator: Operator<string>;
} | {
  field: "age";
  value: number;
  operator: Operator<number>;
} */
```

Looks good.  The programmatically-created type `FilterItem<Test>` is equivalent to the manually-created `FilterItemTest`, and so our work is now complete.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAICy5QFdwBtUBvYVU1AFwE940AxASz3OgCcBJZyAFTnNQF4iJMiIBm9aHgAmALlQAiCDHkBuYSNIA3fNmhzY5FvVABzNRrIB7Gi3DlLLOfIPgW5WAHd65ABbzUAD4KUpZwoJbu5K7kXr7+QfLQAI7xCqDJquqoAL6BQhak4pKyCuAm0JkFqNp4unI4kABGrOYF1qx2Dk4ZeYoZraTZICJ40HziTKxyDJPsnDwGA6gTzCwCRMsS0nIA5GXQOwA01Tp6qACMAAzH7bb2jgo9uQD0z6iWANbglFkrrOuETbFXb7I4nWpnHbMAxg26dB47FxuTzeHw7HKoV6oVgsBzHGq6VD0WBE0BISyQRDkeiNUa-RirAFA7aoPblMEEs5XG42eG7JHuWJojFYnF4968+5EknGcmUuw0uliBn-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)