# Typescript property type check

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Considering the following code example:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type Filter<Entity> = {
  field: keyof Entity;
  operator: '=' | '!=' | '<=' | '>=';
  value: string | number;
};

const ageFilter: Filter<Person> = {
  field: 'age',
  operator: '>=',
  value: 'some string value',
};
```

Is it possible to define value property of Filter type the way that Typescript would check if correct value type is used - string for person name and number for age? Now for Typescript it's perfectly fine - I can set string value for age filter.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126896/is-there-a-way-define-a-second-property-type-based-on-a-key-used-in-a-separate-p?rq=2